# machine learning text classification

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, text-classification

I'm working on a mini project classification texts with Python.
The idea is simple: we have a corpus of sentences respectively belonging to J. Chirac and Mitterrand (2 ex presidents of French republic (with associated labels).
The goal is to build a model that predicts that belong to different sentences. for classes (labels) it has "M" for Mitterand and "C" for Chirac, correctly in my program I considered that `M == > -1`, and `C ==> 1`.
Finally, I applied a clustering algorithm on my dataset that is called Naive Bayes, and I made a prediction on new data (Test).
The problem here is that after the evaluation of performance of my system, I got a very low score, although I have used several methods to increase (stopwords, bigrams, smoothing ..)

If someone with another idea or suggestion for me to improve the performance of my system, I will be very satisfied.

I will attach below some of my code.

In the following code I chose my stopliste and I deleted the words that are not very important and splitters to produce my corpus, and I use bigrams:

```
stoplist = set('le la les de des à un une en au ne ce d l c s je tu il que qui mais quand'.split())
stoplist.add('')
splitters = u'; |, |\*|\. | |\'|'
liste = (re.split(splitters, doc.lower()) for doc in alltxts) # generator = pas de place en memoire
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([u"{0}_{1}".format(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(l)-1)] for l in liste) # bigrams
print len(dictionary)
stop_ids = [dictionary.token2id[stopword] for stopword in stoplist   if stopword in dictionary.token2id]
once_ids = [tokenid for tokenid, docfreq in dictionary.dfs.iteritems() if docfreq < 10 ]
dictionary.filter_tokens(stop_ids + once_ids) # remove stop words and words that appear only once
dictionary.compactify() # remove gaps in id sequence after words that were removed
print len(dictionary)
liste = (re.split(splitters, doc.lower()) for doc in alltxts) # ATTENTION: quand le générator a déjà servi, il ne se remet pas au début => le re-créer pour plus de sécurité 
alltxtsBig = ([u"{0}_{1}".format(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(l)-1)] for l in liste)
corpusBig = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in alltxtsBig]
```

and here, I produce a corpus for my test dataset:

```
liste_test = (re.split(splitters, doc.lower()) for doc in alltxts_test)
alltxtsBig_test = ([u"{0}_{1}".format(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(l)-1)] for l in liste_test)
corpusBig_test = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in alltxtsBig_test]
and here I am doing the processing of these data has a numpy matrix, and I apply the algorithm on data, and I make the prediction on test data:


dataSparse = gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(corpusBig)
dataSparse_test = gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(corpusBig_test)
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text as txtTools #.TfidfTransformer
t = txtTools.TfidfTransformer()
t.fit(dataSparse.T)
data2 = t.transform(dataSparse.T)
data_test = t.transform(dataSparse_test.T)
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(data2, labs)
y_nb_predicted = nb_classifier.predict(data_test)
```

**Edit:**
The performance of my system gives a value of 0.28. Normally if the system is effective it will give more than 0.6.
I work on a file Millers sentences, and I declared gensim, I did not paste all the code here because it's very long, my question is just if there are other methods of improve system performance, I have used bigrams, smoothing .. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. First of all, are you *sure* you're getting poor performance? You're not even saying what performance you get, but if (as you seem to be saying) you're trying to identify the author on the basis of a *single* sentence, I wouldn't expect that it's possible with any kind of reliability. Author identification is usually done on much longer texts.

I'm afraid your code is both incomplete (where is `gensim` defined? What do all these library functions do?) and too long to follow easily. But are you using the presence of all (non-stopword) bigrams in the text as the features for your classifier? That's a lot of features, and they're all of the same kind (bigrams). You can try to add some different kinds of features to the mix, and/or use bigram features more selectively to avoid overtraining. You should read up to find out what kind of things are likely to work-- author identification is hardly a new task.

Your question is a bit too broad to answer effectively, because there are too many possible answers. But stick around and ask more specific questions as you work on this more. Good luck!